# Executing batch files using process and runtime classes

Tags: java, batch-file, file-io

I am trying to have my program write a batch file that will end the JVM, and delete the jar file that is running.
I have concluded through debugging that the batch file is not being executed. Here is the relevant code.

```
public void stopKill() {
    try {
        //The batch file we are writing to
        File killFile = new File("E:\\killFile.bat");
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(killFile);
        //The jar file that is currently running.
        File jarFile = new File(networkCheck.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        output.println("taskkill /IM javaw.exe /F");
        output.println("del \"" + jarFile.toString() + "\"");
        output.close();
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        //Execute the batch file
        try {
            Process p = r.exec(killFile.toString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Uh-oh!");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(networkCheck.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(networkCheck.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

Here is the text that is printed to the batch file, when this function is called on my system.

```
taskkill /IM javaw.exe /F
del "C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\Coding\Java\NetworkCheck\dist\NetworkCheck.jar"
```

Thank you for the help in advance. If there is any information that is in need of clarification, please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `r.exec( "cmd.exe /c start \"E:\\killFile.bat\"" );`